# I can't texture paint!

Tags: texture-painting

I can't paint! My faces aren't inverted, I'm on the correct tool, and I've linked my nodes. Not to mention, I've reset my UV wrap and material multiple times. I don't know how to approach this; can anyone help?

P.S -- I *Have* gone through every forum I can find, and none of them have solved the issue...[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, please share your file, use https://blend-exchange.com/ ... also please avoid "Can someone please help?" in the title, everybody is here for help   ;)

Comment: Hello! Sorry for the mistakes; I'm just a newb :) [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=ssvYszsd" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/ssvYszsd/)

Answer (score 1):

You have loaded a texture and a texture mask (plus they are both black so you can't paint anything), close them both in the *N panel > Tool*:

[image]